# Export data and images (all content) from Wordpress to another page

Tags: php, wordpress

Is it possible to export data and photos (all content) from Wordpress to another website (not based on WP)?
I wanted to move the content of a WP-based website to my site (author's CMS) and I wonder how it's the easiest thing to do.
I am interested in moving both content and content (photos etc).

Does anyone know how to do it the easiest way?

Comment: Do you want to migrate from one Wordpress to another Wordpress ? Or Did you mean like from Wordpress to any other CMS?

Comment: No. I want migrate from Wordpress to my CMS (authors - not Wordpress)

Comment: Have a look at the WP Rest api. You should be able to get the content using this.